# Regex for all capital letters between last 2 parentheses in string

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

I'm trying to get all capital letters between the last 2 parentheses in a string. So far I've tried this:

```
/\(([A-Z])([^)]*)\)[^(]*$/g
```

On for example: I don't want (These Words), I want (These Two)

but it gives me:

Group 1. `T`

Group 2. `hese Two`

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want all letters, not just capital letters? What answer do you want?

Comment: It would be easier to maintain if you get the index of the last opening parenthesis, then get the index of the last closing parenthesis, and get the substring between those indexes, *then* get the capital letters.  Even if you get your regex working, there's no way you'll understand the regex in a few months.

Comment: Can your string have many sets of parentheses? Can there be error cases where there are mismatched parentheses? Or, are there always only two you have to deal with and NO error conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, the shortest and simplest solution is:

- `(?!.*\()` - Negative lookahead - nowhere later can occur any
  opening parenthesis (after any number of other chars),
- `(?=.*\))` - Positive lookahead - somewhere later there must
  occur the closing parenthesis (after any number of other chars),
- `[A-Z]` - Catch a capital letter, not as a capturing group,
  but as a "normal" match,
- `g` - With *global* option.

To sum up:

```
/(?!.*\()(?=.*\))[A-Z]/g
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the capital letters between the last string wrapped between parentheses in JavaScript as follow:

```
/(?!.*\()(?=.*\))([A-Z])/g
```

Where the first part `(?!.*\(.*\))` is a negative lookahead which ignores all the opening parentheses and stops immediately after the last one. Then we perform a positive lookahead which matches everything until it encounters closing parentheses. Then we match the capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

### Code

```js
var s = "I don't want (These Words), I want (These Two)"
var r = /.*\(([^)]*)\)/
var m = r.exec(s)

console.log(m[1].match(/[A-Z]/g))
```

---

### Explanation

#### First Regex

The first regex `.*\(([^)]*)\).*` extracts the contents of the last parentheses.

- `.*` Match any character any number of times
- `\(` Match a left parenthesis literally
- `([^)]*)` Capture any character except the right parenthesis any number of times into capture group 1
- `\)` Match a right parenthesis literally
- `.*` Match any character any number of times

#### Second Regex

The second regex `[A-Z]` matches uppercase letters

Comment: Thanks, but is there no way of doing this in one expression?

    s.match(/.*\(([^)]*)\).*/)[1].match(/[A-Z]/g).join('')

Would work, but it'd be nicer if I could put it in 1 regex

Comment: @TimVN why do people always ask that? Haha... It is but not in JavaScript when you're talking the possibility of variable length elements. If you always have 2 words you can use `.*\(([A-Z])[^A-Z]([A-Z])` and get the first and second capture groups. But the moment you add the possibility for this to have more or less, your expression becomes extremely convoluted: `.*\(([A-Z])(?:[^A-Z]([A-Z]))?` -> 1 or 2, `.*\(([A-Z])(?:[^A-Z]([A-Z]))?(?:[^A-Z]([A-Z]))?` -> 1,2, or 3, etc.

Comment: @TimVN in other regex engines this is possible. JavaScript's regex support isn't fantastic. PCRE, for example, allows `\G` and `\K` which makes this super easy: [`(?:.*\(|\G(?!\A))[^A-Z]*\K[A-Z]`](https://regex101.com/r/9e2GLA/1/) but these aren't available in JavaScript. You can do this without `\K` as such: [`(?:.*\(|\G(?!\A))[^A-Z]*([A-Z])`](https://regex101.com/r/9e2GLA/2), but again `\G` isn't supported in JavaScript.

Comment: @TimVN C# also allows to do this (without `\G` token) but that's because it keeps all captures: [`.*\((?:[^A-Z]*([A-Z]))*`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=.*%5c%28%28%3f%3a%5b%5eA-Z%5d*%28%5bA-Z%5d%29%29*&i=I+don%27t+want+%28These+Words%29%2c+I+want+%28These+Two%29)